# averange randomForest predictions in Spark 1.3.1

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm trying to calculate an averange of randomForest predictions in Spark 1.3.1, since the predicted probability of all trees will be available only in future versions.

The best I could do until now is using the function below:

```
def calculaProbs(dados, modelRF):
    trees = modelRF._java_model.trees()
    nTrees = modelRF.numTrees()
    nPontos = dados.count()
    predictions = np.zeros(nPontos)
    for i in range(nTrees):
        dtm = DecisionTreeModel(trees[i])
        predictions += np.array(dtm.predict(dados.map(lambda x: x.features)).collect())
    predictions = predictions/nTrees
    return predictions
```

This code is running too slow, as expected, since I'm collecting predictions from each Tree and adding them up in Driver.
I cannot put the $dtm.predit()$ inside a Map operation in this version of Spark. Here is the Note from documentation: "Note: In Python, predict cannot currently be used within an RDD transformation or action. Call predict directly on the RDD instead."

Any Idea to improve performance? How can I add values from 2 RDDs without collecting their values to a vector?

Comment: I think that the problem might be that you are collecting all the entries and that is very expensive, a better approach is to `reduce` the results and **adding** all the entries for predictions and then divide the result by the number of trees.

Comment: Each iteration on i is the prediction of one specific Tree. I have to avg the results of all Trees for each point. I cannot use reduce in each iteration. `dtm.predict()` returns an RDD.